# Integrate $\frac{1}{a-\cos x}$ from $0$ to $2\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I would like to evaluate the integral:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a-\cos x}dx$$
Surprisingly, I could find a lot of standard results for similar integrals like $\int\frac{1}{1+a\cos x}dx$ or $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a-\cos x}}dx$ but not this one.

Sorry if the answer is easy to find, perhaps I am just blind.

Comment: $a-\cos x=a(1-\dfrac1a\,\cos x)$, $-\cos x=\cos(x+\pi)$. You probably need $a>1$ for the integral to converge.

Comment: Did you try to multiply and divide by $a$ and then substituting $b={1 \over a}$?

Comment: Handbook (mine is the '83 edition). Formula 15.44.

Comment: Are you serious ? $a-\cos(x)=a(1+\dfrac1{-a}\cos(x))$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$u=\tan\frac{x}{2}$$ then
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a-cosx}dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{a-cosx}dx=\frac{4}{a+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^2+\frac{a-1}{a+1}}du=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $a>1$,
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{a-\cos x}&=&\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\frac{1}{a-\cos x}+\frac{1}{a+\cos x}\right)\,dx\\ &=& \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{2a\,dx}{a^2-\cos^2 x}\\&=&4a\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{a^2-\cos^2 x}\\(x=\arctan t)\quad&=&4a\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{a^2(1+t^2)-1}\\(t=s\sqrt{a^2-1})\quad&=&\color{red}{\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}}.\end{eqnarray*} $$

Comment: Explain your downvotes, please.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'll admit that I find the last step less-than-transparent. Writing the last substitution as $x=\text{arctan }at$ might help.